# Prestashop concatenate id_product with size

Tags: php, prestashop

I need to know how I can concatenate ID of a product with its size from cart page using php.
The idea is to be able to take the ID of a product with his size in this format: 1922-41, 1922 is the ID product and 41 is the size.
I know that the variable $product has many attributes but I'm not clear how to get the size of a certain product from the cart page.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: But where do you want to add this code?

Comment: I need do this in php and then past it to an hook.

Comment: But in a controller, in a module..? Could you paste some code?